# Python function that navigates to top level module directory

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to write a function in python that navigates to the top level directory of the project i'm working on for bookkeeping purposes. Instead of writing abs paths everywhere which may change depending on the machine, I think this would be easier.

However, my funct isn't super sophisticated and goes into inf loops in situations. Does anyone have a good strategy for something like this?

```
def chdir_top():
    while os.getcwd().split('/')[-1] != "myproj":
        os.chdir('..')
    if os.getcwd().split('/')[-2] != "myproj" and 
               "myproj" in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        os.chdir("myproj")
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at os.path.join() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `os.getcwd()` for this; use the module-level `__file__` name instead. If the current working directory is *elsewhere*, you end up in an infinite loop when you reach the root directory and continually fail to go up one directory.

```
import os.path

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Now `here` is a path to the directory containing the current Python file. Use that to find the top of your project (*not* by using `chdir()` but by using `os.path` functions).

Comment: Ah, so how about this. here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))   os.chdir(here)   while os.getcwd().split('/')[-1] != 'myprojroot': os.chdir('..')

Comment: os.getcwd() should be safe if we are assuring that we chdir into somewhere

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang: why use `chdir()` **at all**?

Comment: sorry, im not super familiar with the os module. How would this be done via os.path?

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang: You'd store `here` in the *top level module* of your project; that way you already have the top-level directory without having to go 'up'. You can also use `os.path.join()` and `os.path.normpath()` to add `..` path elements to the `here` variable and have those resolved into an absolute path that is a few levels 'up'.

Comment: If you really want to do something like the original version, you can always loop walking up one level at a time (from `__file__`) until you reach a directory named `myproj` (and error if you reach the top, instead of looping forever). But really, if you know the structure of your package or project (and you should…), it's better to just put `here` at the top, as Martijn Pieters explains.

Comment: thanks a lot you guys, ill mark as answered in a sec but still curious. how do you "You'd store here in the top level module of your project; that way you already have the top-level directory without having to go 'up'. " Sorry, just have never seen this before!

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang: Any Python file in the `myproj` dir is *already* at the top level, thus their `__file__` value is going to be `/path/to/myproj/somemodule.py` and the result of my code is `/path/to/myproj`. No need to navigate up at all in that case.